# Difference in months between dates with different rows (same identifier) (in R)

Tags: r, difference

```
 cpf sep_month hire_month hire_year sep_day  hire_date   sep_date
4 123         4          2      2012       1 2012-02-01 2013-04-01
5 123         0          4      2013       1 2013-04-01       <NA>
6 122        10          9      2012       1 2012-09-01 2013-10-01
7 122         0         12      2013       1 2013-12-01       <NA>

structure(list(cpf = c(123L, 123L, 122L, 122L), sep_month = c(4L, 
0L, 10L, 0L), hire_month = c(2L, 4L, 9L, 12L), hire_year = c(2012L, 
2013L, 2012L, 2013L), sep_day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), hire_date = structure(c(15371, 
15796, 15584, 16040), class = "Date"), sep_date = structure(c(15796, 
NA, 15979, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = 4:7, class = "data.frame")
```

In my dataset, each row is a job contract. I want to see the difference in months between sep_date and hire_date across different rows for the same CPF (identifier).
For example, individual 123 separated from its job on 2013-04. On the following row, he was hired (under a different contract/job) on 2013-04. My goal is to create a dummy equal to 1 for individuals who separated from a contract and found a job in the same or following month. That would be the case for individual 123, but not for individual 122.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: I am sorry. I now have corrected it. Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(cpf) %>%
  mutate(dummy = sapply(sep_date, function(z) any(!is.na(z) & z <= hire_date))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 8
#     cpf sep_month hire_month hire_year sep_day hire_date  sep_date   dummy
#   <int>     <int>      <int>     <int>   <int> <date>     <date>     <lgl>
# 1   123         4          2      2012       1 2012-02-01 2013-04-01 TRUE 
# 2   123         0          4      2013       1 2013-04-01 NA         FALSE
# 3   122        10          9      2012       1 2012-09-01 2013-10-01 TRUE 
# 4   122         0         12      2013       1 2013-12-01 NA         FALSE
```

If you want `dummy` to be truly just `1`s and `0`s, then add a `+` before it, as in `dummy = +sapply(...)` (`+` is a shortcut to convert `logical` to `integer`).

### base R

```r
dat$dummy <- ave(
  seq_along(dat$cpf), dat$cpf,
  FUN = function(i) sapply(dat$sep_date[i], function(z) any(!is.na(z) & z <= dat$hire_date[i])))
dat
#   cpf sep_month hire_month hire_year sep_day  hire_date   sep_date dummy
# 4 123         4          2      2012       1 2012-02-01 2013-04-01     1
# 5 123         0          4      2013       1 2013-04-01       <NA>     0
# 6 122        10          9      2012       1 2012-09-01 2013-10-01     1
# 7 122         0         12      2013       1 2013-12-01       <NA>     0
```

This is a little uglier because `ave` doesn't like doing multi-column (multi-vector) stuff, but it gets the same results.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! However, I think I might still have a problem since the dummy is 1 for individual 122, which I would want to be 0 since he separated from a given contract (row) on 2013-10 and only got a new job (different contract, different row) on 2013-12, which is more than one month away. I would like a possibility that could also handle more than one job transition (in the sample dataset, each individual moved between jobs only once, but this could happen potentially more times).

Comment: I thought of replacing the NA in sep_date for the latest sep_date (for each individual) and then calculating the difference between months, but I do not know how to do it nor if it would be adequate.

Comment: dat2 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(cpf) %>% 
  summarise(max_sep_date = max(sep_date, na.rm = TRUE))

I have used this code to find the latest sep_date for each id, but I do not know how to replace the NA's for such dates